# JAX-WS Exception

Tags: java, exception, jax-ws, fault

How to assign the **fault** field of the **SOAPFaultException** on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the only way to assign a fault field is through [the constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException.html#SOAPFaultException(javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault)).  So, the easiest way would be to create a new `SOAPFaultException` with the fault as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

define exception

```
public class SomeFault extends Exception
{
   public SomeFault(String code)
   {
   }

   public String getA() {...}
   public void setA() {..}

   public String getB() {...}
   public void setB() {..}
}
```

and then webservice

```
@WebService
public class MyWS
{
   public MyWS()
   {
   }

   public Response getSomething(String id) throws SomeFault 
   {
      throw new SomeFault(id);
   }
}
```